# Ignore toggle on larger screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize, window

I have the following menu on the right of my header:

```
<ul class="right-menu">
  <li class="dg-button">
    <a href="#diagram-popup" class="diagram-btn" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out">
      <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/barrel-slim.png"
        width="25" height="30" alt="Oil production">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="mnr-header-button">
    <a href="https://www.mnronline.com/" target="_blank">
      <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/mnr-logo.png"
        width="125" height="24" alt="MNR Portal">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="slant-menu-item header-social">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/mnrkurdistan?lang=en-gb/" target="_blank">
      <i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="slant-menu-item header-social">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/MNRKurdistan/" target="_blank">
      <i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i>
     </a>
  </li>
  <li class="slant-menu-item header-social">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZ_WWHnSxBEqcQRsaVE8hreHivZbh2bjZ" target="_blank">
      <i class="icon ion-social-youtube" target="_blank"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="slant-menu-item header-social">
    <a href="#contact-popup" class="contact-btn" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out">
      <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
        </a>
  </li>
  <li class="header-social-trigger">
    <a>
      <i class="icon ion-android-share-alt" target="_blank"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the css bit that hides of shows certain items of this menu on screens with certain width:

```
.header-social-trigger {
  display: none!important;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1400px) {
  .header-social-trigger {
    display: table-cell!important;
    background-color: #e0771a!important;
    border-left: 0!important;
  }

  .header-social-trigger:hover {
    background-color: #f1811e!important;
  }

  .header-social {
    display: none!important;
  }
}
```

An finally the jQuery that controls the visibility of some of these items:

```
jQuery.fn.clickToggle = function (a, b) {
  function cb() {
    [b, a][this._tog ^= 1].call(this);
  }
  return this.on("click", cb);
};

$(".header-social-trigger").clickToggle(function () {
  $('.header-social').css("cssText", "display: table-cell!important");
  $('.dg-button, .mnr-header-button').css("cssText", "display: none");
  $('.header-social-trigger .icon').removeClass("ion-android-share-alt");
  $('.header-social-trigger .icon').addClass("ion-close");
}, function () {
  $('.header-social').css("cssText", "display: none");
  $('.dg-button, .mnr-header-button').css("cssText", "display: table-cell");
  $('.header-social-trigger .icon').removeClass("ion-close");
  $('.header-social-trigger .icon').addClass("ion-android-share-alt");
});
```

When I resize the window to a width between 1024 and 1400 it works as expected and some items show and others hide but when i resize it back to a larger width all these items should display but they don't. I guess what I am trying to achieve here is sort of ignore the jQuery which toggles these elements when the window is resized to a larger width. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use screen width and apply condition "screen.width" like if(screen.width > 720) { }

Comment: I have tried this before and can't seem to work.. I have created a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/v5bgp389/18/  When you resize the window you see some buttons hiding. Then if you click on the social share icon that appears the social icons show but when you expand the window back again it does not go to it's original form which is hiding the social share button and show all buttons. This is what I need. I need it to get back to show all buttons when window resize is larger.